# Can I get a list of column names from a joSQL query or its results?

Tags: josql

Is it possible to get the list of column names related to a query or results set? I've been reading the documentation for joSQL but I can't work out if this is possible. I don't see anything in the API to let me do this. But when I debug print the query and results, this information is inside the class. joSQL has a ColumnReference class but I've no idea what uses it or if I can even get to instances of this class. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `Query.getColumns` this will return a list of: `SelectItemExpression` you can then use: `getAlias` on each to return the "column" name.

So:

```
Query q = new Query ();
q.parse ("SELECT a FROM java.lang.String");

List cols = q.getColumns ();

for (int i = 0; i < cols.size (); i++)
{

    SelectItemExpresion sie = (SelectItemExpression) cols.get (i);

    System.out.println (i + ": " + sie.getAlias ());

}
```

Of course if the column doesn't have an alias then you could try using the `toString` method instead or digging around in the `Expression` to find more suitable data.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible,
joSQL is the inMemory filtering utility which uses reflection to filter out the data between two Collections.

JoSQL currently supports the following SQL features:

```
SELECT * (which means "return the object" that matches the where or having clause)
SELECT columns, SELECT function, SELECT expression (arithmetic and boolean), SELECT save value, SELECT bind variable, and any mixture of the previous items
```